# What can't be done with Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows, security, remote-desktop

Windows (let's say Windows 10) comes with Remote Desktop Connection.
If I buy two identical laptop computers and connect them with an
ethernet cable, what can't be done over this connection (but can be
done directly)?

For example, by default, it seems that a User Account Control prompt
can't be answered.  But, Microsoft does allow a registry change to fix
this, so let me reword my problem to consider two identical laptop
computers with their registries modified "for maximum operation".  I'm
trying to find the true limitation of Remote Desktop.

For a second example, I would think that there might be a problem if I
use Remote Desktop to Remote Desktop back to my original computer...but
I've never tried this.  I'm actually wondering if there are examples
without resorting to this recursive limit.

Comment: I've tried playing [Warframe](https://warframe.com/game) over Remote Desktop before.  The game refused to launch, saying it wasn't supported over Remote Desktop or something like that.

Comment: "For example, by default, it seems that a User Account Control prompt can't be answered." I do this all the time in my lab.  Why exactly are you doing to RD RD back to the original PC?

Comment: Just as you noted from the question, the answers could get into recursion and permutations of recursiveness. If you have a specific question we would probably find a specific answer, but as asked this question is too broad to be satisfactorily answered.

Comment: This is a 'list' question. Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can't be done...

I imagine there are others, but this for starters.

Accessing the remote graphics or sound setup, as they're not really running. Instead you are using substitutes

[image]

...which is why you can't play games.

Comment: And which is also why you can't install or update graphics drivers remotely.

Comment: Actually you can install updates, just not via the Control Panel. if you fetch directly from NVidia etc, then they install just fine.

Comment: Oh, that hadn't occurred to me.  Microsoft could have done this differently, but I can see their technical reasons (instead of security reasons, thanks!) to limit things.  If I needed to adjust the true graphics and sound (I would really prefer to just get a remote clone, so the audio, for example, would get played on both computers), I now wonder if there is a better alternative to RD.  My motivation, since people are questioning it, is just to be able to help my grandma out remotely.